# What protein(s) serve as the control antigen in Covid lateral flow tests?

Tags: immunology, coronavirus

Having recently been obliged to take a lateral flow test for Covid in order to fly from the UK, I idly wondered:

> What is the **control** antigen for Covid lateral flow tests?

as (fortunately) that was the only band I saw.

Easy — just Google? You jest! “Other people asked”, “All you need to know” and even the scientific papers linked just talk about the *target* antigen.

This sort of thing really gets up my nose!

Could someone please tell me what it is up my nose?

Comment: You mean the red stripe at the upper control position of the test? See this question where it has been answered: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/101767/whats-happening-in-the-c-and-t-stripes-of-a-covid-test-kit

Comment: @Chris. I see. It is the test antibody itself. So this would seem to control only for addition of the test solution, and not whether I’ve swabbed my nose adequately. Is this correct? If so, it doesn’t seem correct.

Comment: @David, you are correct. Even if you don't swab the nose and put "clean" extraction buffer on the test card, you will get the "C" band. On my tests, even tap water gives the "C" band (although a bit lighter, but still clearly visible).

Comment: Absolutely correct. There is no control if you took the specimen correctly. Luckily most "corona skeptics" do not understand how this test works. As @Domen says, you get the control band with water only. Oh, btw. you can also fake a positive best by using a few drops of apple juice or coke.

Comment: @Domen Thanks. Well I’m waiting for a plane to take me to the ski slopes now. No point in going if I didn’t really test negative. First time in an airport for two years — never seen it so empty. Trust I can negotiate Swiss and French controls.